# Magento. Can't login Admin, after domain move

Tags: magento

Just had Magento moved from one domain to another, but can't log in the admin, even though I could earlier in the day.

I have full access to the DB via PHPmyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Changed the password to MD5 within the database and it seems to let me in.